# the count of row( user) for each table begining with cm in the schema

Tags: mysql, database

I want all the tables' list with corresponding count of number of NULL entries in column 'user'. I have printed all table's name beginning with `cm`  using

```
SELECT
    TABLE_NAME
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE (TABLE_NAME LIKE 'cm%') ;
```

but for each table i want to run

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM <TABLENAME> WHERE `create_user` IS NULL
 OR `create_time` IS NULL
```

and print

Comment: Right so for each result of query 1, you run the second query

Comment: Or are you asking how to do this ALL IN ONE QUERY

Comment: How do i make a single query combining the two?

Comment: yes @RiggsFolly i am asking to do it in ONE query.

Answer (score 0):

Create the table below, replacing it with the correct database name:

```
CREATE TABLE `db`.`tbl_count_null` (
  `tableschema` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `tablename` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `qtd` char(0) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

See if the procedure below meets you:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`%` PROCEDURE `nameprocedure`()
BEGIN
  DECLARE x, y LONGTEXT;
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE databasesCursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'cm%';
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
                    FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done = 1;

        OPEN databasesCursor;
            myLoop: LOOP
                FETCH databasesCursor INTO x, y;

                IF NOT done THEN
                    SET @query = CONCAT("INSERT INTO`db`.`tbl_count_null` (tableschema, tablename, qtd) SELECT '",x,"' AS `schema`,'",y,"' AS `table`,COUNT(1) FROM `",x,"`.`",y,"` WHERE `create_user` IS NULL OR `create_time` IS NULL;");
                    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
                    EXECUTE stmt;
                    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

                END IF;
            END LOOP myLoop;

        CLOSE databasesCursor;
END;
```

After creating the above procedure, call with the command:

```
call db.nameprocedure;
```

Verify that the records have been inserted into the table **`db`.`tbl_count_null`**

Comment: I want a single query so far i have used
SELECT information_schema.tables table_rows AS total_rows
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = <schemaname> AND information_schema.tables LIKE 'cm%' by using this i get 2 columns 1 having the table name and other with the total row count can you suggest anyway i get the column as the count of `create_user` IS NULL  OR `create_time` IS NULL